# custom divs in a div container without overlapping issue

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to create divs inside a div with mouse move over and mouse click the link below is somewhat I need but after hours of research, I am unable to get rid of the overlapping issue and an array on existing divs coordinates.

Here is jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/d9BPz/546/

```
initDraw(document.getElementById('canvas'));

function initDraw(canvas) {
    function setMousePosition(e) {
        var ev = e || window.event; //Moz || IE
        if (ev.pageX) { //Moz
            mouse.x = ev.pageX + window.pageXOffset;
            mouse.y = ev.pageY + window.pageYOffset;
        } else if (ev.clientX) { //IE
            mouse.x = ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
            mouse.y = ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        }
    };

    var mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0
    };
    var element = null;

    canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
        setMousePosition(e);
        if (element !== null) {
            element.style.width = Math.abs(mouse.x - mouse.startX) + 'px';
            element.style.height = Math.abs(mouse.y - mouse.startY) + 'px';
            element.style.left = (mouse.x - mouse.startX < 0) ? mouse.x + 'px' : mouse.startX + 'px';
            element.style.top = (mouse.y - mouse.startY < 0) ? mouse.y + 'px' : mouse.startY + 'px';
        }
    }

    canvas.onclick = function (e) {
        if (element !== null) {
            element = null;
            canvas.style.cursor = "default";
            console.log("finsihed.");
        } else {
            console.log("begun.");
            mouse.startX = mouse.x;
            mouse.startY = mouse.y;
            element = document.createElement('div');
            element.className = 'rectangle'
            element.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
            element.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
            canvas.appendChild(element)
            canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: From your question it is not very clear what you want to achieve, and what you get instead... Try elaborating on this please...

Comment: You can try creating a Fiddle of your own that shows your exact problem

Comment: My problem is overlapping of divs, what i need is a an array of existing divs coordinates and new div should not be overlap on other divs